# Upgrading Spring boot 2.0.1 to Spring 2.0.4

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

Is there a way to Upgrade a existing spring boot 2.0.1 project to a spring 2.0.4 project ? Such as overriding the maven dependencies ?

Comment: 2.0.1 to 2.0.4 is upgrading not downgrading ;) you can change it in maven

Comment: did you use any of the starter dependency?